# I can't turn off widescreen on my LG Flatron W2246

Tags: display, widescreen

I want to know how you can turn off widescreen on an LG Flatron W2246.

Comment: What do you want to have instead, black borders to the left and right of the image? What OS are you using, and what resolution do you want to have? Doesn't it just work simply selecting a different non-native resolution, and if not, what's the error message?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that model has the "4:3 in Wide" mode.  If engaged, it stretches 4:3 resolutions to fit the 16:10 screen.

To toggle it, it will either just be a button on the front panel, or you may have to set it using the buttons and the On-Screen Display menu of the monitor.